# Calling Mono from PHP

Tags: php, mono

it's a bit complicated. :-) I have a website written in PHP that needs to call an external program written in .NET, running under Mono. It calls the program with:

```
/path/mono /path/executable arguments...
```

as per usual (I also tried to put this into a bash script and call the script itself from PHP).

As far as I can tell, everything is set up as required. Mono itself running all right, executable (or script) with executable rights, owners are all right. The correct setup can also be ascertained from the fact that if I issue the command line above (or call the script mentioned) from a command line on the server (Debian Lenny), everything works perfectly, my executable is executed without error.

But, if PHP calls the same (using exec(), system() or any other variant), I immediately get an exit code of 6 from Mono and my executable is not run at all (in order to test it, I use a "Hello World" executable that does nothing but emits a single output line and returns 0). Compiled without any additional dependency, just a real "Hello Word". It's absolutely sure that this program doesn't return the exit code 6, it must come from Mono but I couldn't find it documented anywhere.

I can call anything else from PHP, so it's not safe mode or any similar restriction that would keep me from executing external programs from PHP.

Thanks for any idea...

Comment: Mono has great support for web services.  If you're simply trying to execute something written in .NET, why not expose it via service?

Comment: Are you invoking the PHP script via webserver, or from command line? Remember that PHP's setup is generally quite different when it's in CLI mode v.s. SAPI mode.

Comment: It's a very, very bad idea to use `exec()`.

Comment: During testing, I try every kind of invoking. The final goal would be to call it from the CMS itself, from its regularly triggered cron job. Actually, during the most part of testing, I do call it from the cron job, only that I trigger it manually.

Comment: Peter, probably because it's rather comfortable to develop such a console application (it's about some file conversions) on Windows, without the need for any web server setup and the simply upload it to the server for execution. While I could rewrite it to a service, I still won't understand what that error 6 means...

Comment: Look into the `error.log`, or try the `mono --debug` option and/or setting `MONO_LOG_LEVEL=info mono code.exe`. Otherwise you'll have to look into the mono source to figure out what errlevel 6 means (useless manpage).

Comment: @Mario, nothing seems to help, I guess it doesn't even start executing my exe, so no debugging info to return. Off I went to the source. Sigh.

Comment: <A dozen or so expletives deleted> Error 6 is MONO_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY. The memory allocated to PHP is not enough. Bother, could have guessed, of course, in hindsight. If only Mono gave a sensible error message to start with... Thanks, @Mario, yours was the winning idea.

Answer (score 2):

Try to execute mono from the command line but with the user running the webserver (www-data or apache).

ej.

```
#su apache
$/path/to/mono /path/to/program.exe
```

The common problems that I have using exec is a different environment variables (look if is bash or sh what apache is using), permissions to the user/group of apache, etc.